# Can match cells while those two cells are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using excel to create an semi-automatic bank recon file.
I copy numbers from Bank website, and from sage Intacct GL report.

But when I use the index-match function, the excel does not match large numbers. ( all number smaller than 100,000 works, but when the number is larger or equal to 100,000, the function shows #N/A)

There is no space in cell [tried =Trim(), =value(), =len()]
and cell1= cell2 when using =if(c1=c1, true, false), it shows true.

//it sometimes works when I copy then paste value only, then double click the cell, but I have no idea why that would work

Comment: For some reason the larger numbers are being stored as text and as such a number to text is not being matched.  This is a total guess, without seeing the data.

Comment: I agree with @ScottCraner. Could you try creating an auxiliary column with a formula that sums 0 to your values? Then try index-match on that

Comment: If `=c1=c2` returns true when comparing a copied number to a manually entered number, then that implies the data is okay and I would double check the index-match function to make sure it includes the full range of lookup values.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your advises! @Michael, ScottCraner, and Lucas. I tried all your suggestions, but I have no idea why those are still not working. (please see those new images I have attached above) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah your match function is weird. You shouldn't have just a single cell as the 2nd argument. Have a look at this page on how match function works: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function Maybe also let us know what you're trying to achieve and we can let you know how to use Match properly or maybe something else you should be using instead.

Comment: Please share your worksheet (where you took the screenshots) via google sheet or one drive, and confirm where did you copy the data from and what format were used in the source.

Comment: well, the match function works after I upload my excel to google drive. I have no idea why, but this might just be a bug or something

Comment: I see a solidly valid excel issue ticket here... "(0_x)